# jquery getting icon from <li> tag and place it to a dropdown icon in button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created dropdown with accordion using bootstrap. what im going to do is when they click dropdown header `<li>` get icon and place it to dropdown button

```
 <button class="btn btn-search catbutton dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
 span class="label-icon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
    </button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu accordion" role="menu">
    <li role="presentation" class="have-child"> 
        <a class="link" role="menuitem">
            <i class="fa fa-building"></i>Properties<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>  
        </a>

        <ul id="properties" class="panel-collapse collapse submenu">
            <li><a>All</a></li>
            <li><a>Property For Sale</a></li>
            <li><a>Property For Rent</a></li>
            <li><a>Land For Sale</a></li>                                                 
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have manage to get the text and place it there but not the icon down below

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
    $(".catbutton").text($(this).text());
});
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: where is `catbutton` ?

Comment: its the one toggleing dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this 
js should be as follow

```
   $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
      $(".catbutton").html($(this).find('.geticon').html());
    });
```

HTML needs to change as follow

```
<div class="geticon"><i class="fa fa-building"></i>
```

adding class for icon what i need to get and add there is the solution for these

thank you  guradio for guide me

Answer (score 0):

You are just working with **text** not **html** ,if you want the icon onclick then

try this

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
    $(".catbutton").html($(this).html());
});
```

I thing it will help you.

Comment: how to get only icon on there